# SQL Server : rows out of order

Tags: sql-server, insert

When I do a simple query using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio I would expect the rows to be in order based on the `ID` column which is my primary key column.

For the most part the rows are in order but every once in awhile it will go from `98,99,100,1035,1036,1037,101` but when it jumps around it is in groups not just a single row out of order. The rows are added to the database using a simple `INSERT` from a `ColdFusion script`.

Is there a reason this is happening? I can do a `ORDER BY` so it is readable but if there is something I am doing incorrectly to start with I would like to fix my error.

Let me know if any more information would help.

Comment: You're assumption is **wrong** - a relational database **never** has any "system-imminent", "natural" order - you ***ONLY*** get a specific order when you **explicitly** define an `ORDER BY` on your `SELECT`. See [Without ORDER BY there is no default sort order](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/20/without-order-by-there-is-no-default-sort-order.aspx) for more details and an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS SQL Server makes no guarantee about the order in which records are actually stored internally.  So you can't depend on records coming out in the order of the primary key.  If you want to order your result set, then use `ORDER BY` with an appropriate column; it's what it was designed for.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping it was something like that and not something my script was doing. Of course I will continue to use ORDER BY I was just curious on why it returned the rows like that when ORDER BY was not used. Thanks for the info.